# how to increase WAS liberty server messages.log file size?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, logfile, server.xml

Good day,

I have a mobilefirst app deploy in WAS liberty profile. I found that the messages.log is only 72kb and then it will roll to new log file.

I would like to increase the log file size, so I am doing the following way in server.xml, but it does not take effect:

```
<logging traceFileName="messages.log" maxFileSize="20" />
```

or

```
<logging maxFileSize="0"/>
```

May I know how to increase the log file size? My WAS liberty profile is v8.5.5.5. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAS Liberty logging configuration is described here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html

The logging system can be configured to operate a rolling fileset, with the number of files specified by maxFiles and the file size in MB specified by maxFileSize.

So for example, this config will result in a logging fileset of 10 files each up to 1 GB

`<logging maxFileSize="1024" maxFiles="10" />`

Comment: It still does not work for this configuration. The messages.log is still 73kb only.

Comment: The default maxFileSize is 20MB. Either your config is only generating 73 KB of messages.log output, or some other configuration in server.xml is changing the default? Check the server.xml for any other 'logging' elements.
When you say "the messages.log is 73kb only" what does that mean, exactly? What happens after the messages.log reaches that size?

Comment: i see my server.xml, no more 'logging' elements. When it reach 73kb, it will become backup file with append datetime at behind, and then generate another new log. This is because i put maxFiles=0 , so my log files number will have no limit. if I no put this, the messages.log maximum only 2 files.

Comment: Are you sure that server is not restarted? Message log will be created each time server is restarted. And if it is only 73kb maybe you should attach it to the question as it will be very short